On what delta do I look up my vol for an fx Option?
I have a smile where I need to look up vols based on delta.
But in FX option space, you speak of deltas that are premium-adjusted or not.
So what delta do I need to use to look up on the vol surface?

You need to convert the quoted vols into call and put vols. See https://www.researchgate.net/publication/275905055_A_Guide_to_FX_Options_Quoting_Conventions for details. Usually your vendor has tools to do this for you. E.g. on BBG, OVML will source the appropriate IV directly from OVDV, including all conventions. Doing it manually is cumbersome and needs a lot of attention to detail.

Moreover, implied volatility, calibration and the pricing function need to be consistent. So, you need to ask yourself the meaning of the smile? Has it been calibrated to market prices? If so, that already contains the solution to your question. And if not, ask who gave it to you, what they actually mean by it.

As the above two comments from @AKdemy and @Andrea have made apparent you must be aware of what delta types you are using in order for this to make sense. There are generally 4 types:

forward
spot
forward premium adjusted
spot premium adjusted

In my library both the Smile/Surface are labelled as being constructed under one type and FXOptions can be labelled as being a different delta type. The library will make automatic conversions between the two, but this is non-trivial and in the slowest cases requires roots solvers (generally when going from non-premium adjusted to premium adjusted or vice-versa). Some of the mechanics of what is going on here uses the cited paper https://www.researchgate.net/publication/275905055_A_Guide_to_FX_Options_Quoting_Conventions
As an example, suppose one creates an FXDeltaVolSmile specified with a forward delta type:
from rateslib import *  # Python 3.12, rateslib 1.5.0

# Create an FX Forwards market from spot rates and interest rate curves
fxr = FXRates({"eurusd": 1.08}, settlement=dt(2024, 11, 26))
fxc = {
    "eureur": Curve({dt(2024, 11, 26): 1.0, dt(2025, 11, 26): 0.97}),
    "eurusd": Curve({dt(2024, 11, 26): 1.0, dt(2025, 11, 26): 0.97}),
    "usdusd": Curve({dt(2024, 11, 26): 1.0, dt(2025, 11, 26): 0.96}),
}
fxf = FXForwards(fx_rates=fxr, fx_curves=fxc)

# Create a Vol Smile
fxs = FXDeltaVolSmile(
    eval_date=dt(2024, 11, 26),
    expiry=dt(2025, 4, 26),
    nodes={0.25: 10.4, 0.5: 8.4, 0.75: 10.1},
    delta_type="forward"
)


Now if we construct a 25delta Put under the same convention we expect that the vol is exactly 10.4 (as that is an indexed point on the smile)
# Create an FXOption
fxo = FXPut(
    strike="-25d", 
    delta_type="forward", 
    expiry=dt(2025, 4, 26), 
    pair="eurusd"
)
fxo.analytic_greeks(
    curves=[None, fxf.curve("eur", "usd"), None, fxf.curve("usd", "usd")], 
    fx=fxf, 
    vol=fxs
)
####
{'delta': -0.250000,
 '_delta_index': 0.250000,
 '__delta_type': 'forward',
 '__vol': 0.104000,
 '__strike': 1.0391718351025454,
}
####

However, if one constructed a Put under a different delta type definition (such as spot premium adjusted) then the results would be different.
fxo = FXPut(
    strike="-25d", 
    delta_type="spot_pa", 
    expiry=dt(2025, 4, 26), 
    pair="eurusd"
)
fxo.analytic_greeks(
    curves=[None, fxf.curve("eur", "usd"), None, fxf.curve("usd", "usd")], 
    fx=fxf, 
    vol=fxs
)
####
{'delta': -0.250000,
 '_delta_index': 0.243168,
 '__delta_type': 'spot_pa',
 '__vol': 0.104959,
 '__strike': 1.0372647541668385,
}
####

